# Unable to defeat font enumeration for some fonts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, privacy, private-browsing

To enhance privacy and protect myself against fonts fingerprinting in Firefox, I have set in *about:config*: `browser.display.use_documents_fonts = 0`. This setting is meant to disable websites' ability to detect installed fonts.

With JavaScript enabled, I can test which fonts are visible at [Browserleaks](http://www.browserleaks.com/fonts).  When this setting is `1`, nearly 200 fonts are detected in the category `CSS+JS Quick Test`. In the past, setting to `0` would show 0 Font detected.  Now I have a new computer; even when `browser.display.use_documents_fonts = 0`, there are still 5 fonts detected. These are the [MingLiU fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=245).

[image: Browserleaks detects MingLiU fonts even with protection turned ON]

I can find these fonts in `C:\Windows\Fonts` along with many other fonts. I have tried restarting Firefox with a completely fresh profile (no extensions or plugins, or other customization) and I observe the same behavior. I am running **Firefox 41** on **Windows 7 x64**

My question is simple: why are these fonts still showing up when `browser.display.use_documents_fonts = 0`? How can I prevent that from happening? I hope to find something short of deleting the fonts because I don't know whether an application needs them.

Comment: I didn't get any help here. After a while I decided to delete the fonts. Windows refused with an error message to the effect that they are protected system fonts and cannot be deleted. I followed the first 4 steps from this [wikihow.com article](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Protected-System-Fonts-in-Windows-7) and successfully deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

I see that I am late with my answer as you already uninstalled those fonts from your system. If you decide to reinstall those fonts you can prevent their enumeration by doing the following:

Go to about:config. Search for font.blacklist.underline_offset Select it and right click to modify. Delete MingLiU,MingLiU-ExtB,MingLiU_HKSCS,MingLiU-HKSCS-ExtB and PMingLiU,PMingLiU-ExtB Make sure to remove extra comas as well. Click ok Restart Firefox. Go to browserleaks.com and check that they are not enumerated anymore.

Comment: I can't verify this anymore since I no longer have the fonts but I appreciate you taking the time to answer.